# Cannot start redmine: error 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, passenger, redmine

I'm trying to deploy Redmine on my RHEL 6 server. I've checkout the code from SVN and installed all the gems bundled with it.
Then I've installed the passenger module for Apache with `passenger-install-apache2-module` and I obtained all green checks at the end of compilation.
So, here are my configuration:

**rvm info**

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin' is not available,
     usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
     it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
     to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.2.1'.

ruby-2.2.1:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux Kettle 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Feb 1 12:14:02 EST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "redhat/6/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "5 hours 48 minutes 37 seconds ago"
    path:         "/usr/local/rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.2.1p85"
    date:         "2015-02-26"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2015-02-26 revision 49769"
    full_version: "ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]"

   homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/bmc/BladeLogic/8.0/NSH/bin:/opt/bmc/BladeLogic/8.0/NSH/sbin:/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/passenger-5.0.8/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/home/cl027620/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

**gem info**

```
actionmailer (4.2.1)
actionpack (4.2.1)
actionpack-action_caching (1.1.1)
actionpack-xml_parser (1.0.2)
actionview (4.2.1)
activejob (4.2.1)
activemodel (4.2.1)
activerecord (4.2.1)
activesupport (4.2.1)
arel (6.0.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.9.9)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
coderay (1.1.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
fcgi (0.9.2.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
globalid (0.3.5)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
jquery-rails (4.0.3, 3.1.2)
json (1.8.2, 1.8.1)
loofah (2.0.2)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.6.1, 2.5)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.6.1, 5.4.3)
net-ldap (0.11, 0.3.1)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
passenger (5.0.8)
pg (0.18.2, 0.17.1)
power_assert (0.2.2)
protected_attributes (1.0.9)
psych (2.0.8)
rack (1.6.1)
rack-openid (1.4.2)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.1)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.1)
rake (10.4.2)
rbpdf (1.18.5)
rdoc (4.2.0)
redcarpet (3.1.2)
request_store (1.0.5)
ruby-openid (2.3.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sprockets (3.1.0)
sprockets-rails (2.3.1)
test-unit (3.0.8)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
```

**Apache Virtual Host (Apache/2.2.15)
Server built:   Aug 15 2014 03:02:07**

```
Listen *:3000

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName XX.XX.XX.XX
    ServerAdmin myemail@mail.com
    DocumentRoot /data/files/redmine-3.0/public
    ErrorLog logs/redmine_error_log

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/public.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/private.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/ca.pem

    RailsEnv production
    PassengerLoadShellEnvvars off
    PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/passenger-5.0.8
    PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/wrappers/ruby

    #If you are using mod_fcgid and are going to upload files larger than
    #131072 bytes you should consider adding the following line
    #that allows to upload files up to 20 mb
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
            MaxRequestLen 20971520
    </IfModule>

    <Directory "/data/files/redmine-3.0/public">
        AddHandler fastcgi-script fcgi
        Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

When I restart Apache I obtain an error and redmine shows me a 500 friendly error page. The error reports this: http://pastebin.com/f6V7rrFx

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Bitnami Redmine](https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine/installer) installer. It will do all the 'dirty' work for you of installing all appropriate versions of relevant dependencies - without interfering with the main OS versions. It can even work without root permission.

I used this on CentOS, SUSE and Windows - and was always happy...

Comment: Ok tomorrow I'll promptly download it to see if I can surmount faster this step on my RHEL server, thank you. If it works I'll come back to accept your anser.